# Git branching in Visual Studio just show one graph line?

Tags: git, visual-studio, branch

I use Git in Visual Studio as a local version control tool just for myself. Therefore, I have no remote repositories connected and everything runs locally.

My Problem: The Graph only shows one line instead of forked branches.
can somebody explain this, please? Please see the below pictures:
This is what I got:

[image: Visual Studio]

This is what I want:

[image: graph]

If the pictures are unavailable:

```html
What I got:            #    What I want
Graph descr.  Branch #    Graph descr.  Branch
--------------------------------------------------------
O    change2    Test   #   | O     change2   Test
|                      #   | |
O    change1    Test   #   | O     change1   Test
|                      #   |/
O    init       master #   O       init      master
```

I think I have a misunderstanding of how Git actually works, but please help me or show me a good guide.

Thanks in advance !! :)

Comment: I would suggest looking into Get Extensions [http://gitextensions.github.io/](http://gitextensions.github.io/)

It is external to Visual Studio, but its view of the commit graph shows all branches by default.

It is also, in my opinion, easier to work with than the Visual Studio git tooling

Answer (score 2):

If:

- the `DongleFree` branch is made on top of `TestBranch`
- the `TestBranch` branch is made on top of `master`

Then a `git log --oneline --graph --decorate --branches --all` would show the same as Visual Studio: one single line.

Once you have actual concurrent developments (different commits in two different branches, from one common ancestor), you will see forks in the commit graph.

---

The [OP Lexxy_B](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19640110/lexxy-b) confirms in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73287721/git-branching-in-visual-studio-just-show-one-graph-line/73287958#comment129843044_73287958):

> This is exactly the Problem! Visual Studio only shows the current Branch.

And this feature is not yet implemented: "[View history of multiple branches in the same graph](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/how-do-i-view-the-history-of-all-branches-in-git/934801)".

Comment: Hey VonC Thanks for your answer!
I thought I had concurrent developments due to some commits i made on TestBranch.
When do i have concurrent developments?

Comment: @Lexxy_B Switch back to master, and create a new commit: you will see a fork. As noted in the answer: "different commits in two different branches, from one common ancesto".

Comment: Hey @VonC i have done the updates now. But i only see the selected Branch, therefore a fork is only visible when merging it. For me this thing is really confusing somehow. :(

Comment: @Lexxy_B Before merging, can you try in command line a `git log --decorate --oneline --graph --all --branches`; do you see a fork then?

Comment: Yes i can see the forks with that command. Its different from what Visual Studio is showing me

Comment: @Lexxy_B It can be different if the History view of Visual Studio only shows you commits from your current branch. As opposed to the `--all --branches` which shows all branches.

Comment: This is exactly the Problem! Visual Studio only shows the current Branch. I just downloaded Sourcetree to visualize it and it works just the way i want it ! My problem with understanding was : i Couldn't see the other branches. unfortunately i cannot post pictures in the comment (or i don't know how). But now i understood". 
Is there a way to show all Branches at a time in visual Studio? I googled it but was unsuccessful.

Comment: @Lexxy_B "Is there a way to show all Branches at a time in visual Studio?": not to my knowledge, no. I have edited the answer with a link which confirms this feature is still being discussed.

Comment: @Lexxy_B No problem. I hope Microsoft will implement this feature.